# Can we have more robust comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, markdown, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What markdown is available for use within comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21915/what-markdown-is-available-for-use-within-comments)

Is there a way to put html or markdown inside of comments
or at least have the ability to put in some white space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21915/what-markdown-is-available-for-use-within-comments